# How to evaluate this rational limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits

Evaluate:
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+\sin(x^6))(\text{e}^{4\sqrt{x}}-1)}{4\ln (1+x)+x^4-x^6}$$

Comment: There is an extra bracket in the numerator. Is that a typo or should there be a bracket on the left as well?

Comment: Have you tried [L'Hôpital's rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L'H%C3%B4pital's_rule)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exploiting the Taylor series of a function at the point $x=0$, we have

$$ \frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+\sin(x^6))(\text{e}^{4\sqrt{x}}-1)}{4\ln(1+x)+x^4-x^6}$$

$$=\frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+(x^6-\frac{x^{12}}{3!}-\dots )))( (1+4\sqrt{x}+\dots)-1)}{4 (x+\frac{x^2}{2}\dots)+x^4-x^6}$$

$$ \sim \frac{(-3\sqrt{x})(4\sqrt{x})}{4x} = -3. $$

Answer (score 3):

Your limit can be written as

$$
\frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+\sin(x^6))(\text{e}^{4\sqrt{x}}-1)}{4\ln (1+x)+x^4-x^6}
=\frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+o(\sqrt{x}))(4\sqrt{x}+o({\sqrt x}))}{4x+o(x)}
= \frac{-12x +o(x)}{4x+o(x)} \to -3
$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\lim_{x\to0^+}\frac{(-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+\sin(x^6))(\text{e}^{4\sqrt{x}}-1)}{4\ln (1+x)+x^4-x^6} \\= \lim_{x\to0^+} \frac{-3\sqrt{x}+x^3+\sin(x^6)}{\sqrt x} \times \frac{e^{4\sqrt{x}}-1)}{\sqrt x} \times \frac{1}{4\frac{\ln (1+x)}{x} + x^3 - x^5 }$$