# Computing $ \lim_{x \to 0} \left( \frac {1}{x} - \frac {1}{\sin x } \right) $

Tags: limits, trigonometry

How to calculate this limit:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}\left(\frac{1}{x}-\frac{1}{\sin x}\right)$$

All I know is:

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{\sin x}{x} = 1$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \, x = 0$$

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \,\sin x = 0$$

Comment: Can we use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html ?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339533/continuity-of-g-theta-frac12-pi2-theta3-frac-pi2-cot-pi-theta#comment731535_339547) comment. And what's up with that title?

Comment: See also [What is the result of $\lim\limits_{x \to 0}(1/x - 1/\sin x)$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/94864) and  other [questions linked there](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/linked/94864).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Write it as $$\lim_{x\to0}\dfrac{\sin x-x}{x\sin x},$$ and apply L'Hôpital's rule twice.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $\dfrac{1}{x} - \dfrac{1}{\sin x} = \dfrac{\sin x - x}{x\sin x}$, and use L'hopitale rule !