# How can a function be continuous at a point of discontinuity?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, algebra-precalculus

I was reading [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/339533/continuity-of-g-theta-frac12-pi2-theta3-frac-pi2-cot-pi-theta#comment731535_339547) question which asks to prove the continuity of  $$g(\theta) = \frac{1}{2\pi^2\theta^3}-\frac{\pi}{2}\cot(\pi\theta)\csc^2(\pi\theta), 0\le \theta < 1$$ at $\theta=0$

However, by looking at the first term, the function does not appear to be defined at $\theta=0$, and according to [wikipedia](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Calculus/Continuity), a function must be defined at $c$ in order to be continuous at $c$. I am mostly looking for an intuitive explanation, I can't really understand a formal proof since I am not very familiar with infinite series and "big O" notation.

Comment: Such a thing can be interpreted as an assertion that $\lim\limits_{\theta\to0^{+}}g(\theta)$ exists. And that then the function $g$ can be extended to define $g(0)=\lim\limits_{\theta\to0^{+}}g(\theta)$ (which of course makes it continuous at $0$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a lazy way of saying that $g$ (which is a function $(0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$) can be *extended* to a function $\tilde{g}:[0,1)\to\mathbb{R}$ which is continuous at $0$.  That is, there exists some number $c$ such that if you define 
$$\tilde{g}(\theta)=
\begin{cases} 
g(\theta) & \text{ if $0<\theta<1$} \\ 
c & \text{ if $\theta=0$}
\end{cases}$$
then the function $\tilde{g}$ is continuous at $0$.  If you think about what it means for $\tilde{g}$ to be continuous at $0$, it means exactly that $c=\lim_{\theta\to 0^+}g(\theta)$.  So such a continuous extension exists iff the limit $\lim_{\theta\to 0^+}g(\theta)$ exists.