# How can I find the value of this limit

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim _{ { x }\to { 0 } }{ \frac { \sin x-\arctan x }{  {x }^{ 2 }\log(1+x) } }$$

this log is natural logarithm

Comment: If you know the power series for $\sin x$, $\arctan x$, and $\log (1+x)$, then you can apply those, otherwise, this is just a painful L'Hopital's rule problem.

Comment: A [related problem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/307093/how-to-evaluate-this-rational-limit/307132#307132).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [Series Expansion](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SeriesExpansion.html)

$$\frac{\sin x-\arctan x}{x^2\log(1+x)}$$

$$=\frac{x-\frac {x^3}{3!}+O(x^5)-\{x-\frac {x^3}3++O(x^5)\}}{x^3}\cdot\frac1{\frac{\ln(1+x)}x}$$

$$=\frac{x^3(\frac13-\frac16)+O(x^5)}{x^3}\cdot\frac1{\frac{\ln(1+x)}x}$$

$$=\{\frac16+O(x^2)\}\cdot\frac1{\frac{\ln(1+x)}x}\text{ if }x\ne0$$

If $x\to0,x\ne0$

Comment: i.e., 1/6. You could also find this with WolframAlpha, where it gives a step-by-step solution.

Comment: @HanhwaEagles, We know, $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\ln(1+h)}h=1$

Comment: Thank you. yeah, we know $lim _{h→0} ln(1+h)/ h  =1$

Comment: @HanhwaEagles, my pleasure.